# Java How to invert a BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

I need to invert a `BigInteger`.

Let's say i have    `BigInteger x;` and i need to calculate `x.modPow(new BigInteger("-1"), p)`.

I receive the following error:    `java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger not invertible`.

Comment: sorry, i'm retarded. I haven't seen the method    modInverse(BigInteger m) from BigInteger.

Comment: If you're seeing an error with `modPow(-1, p)`, you should be seeing the same error with `modInverse(p)`. What kind of values are you using for x and p? Can you give us any further information?

Comment: p, q, r are large prime numbers. p = 2qr + 1. I need to calculate the ((invert of x) mod q), x from Zq*.

Comment: Strange. Have you verified with `isProbablePrime(k)` where k is large (e.g. 1000 or more) that the numbers are, in fact, prime?

Comment: I generate q and r with `probablePrime(int bitLength, Random rnd)` from BigInteger. Let's say i have g from Zp*. What i need to do is (raise g at power x) mod p, then the (result raised at power y) mod p, then (the new result raised at the invert of x) mod p, and i should obtain g. But this doesn't happen.

Comment: So q and r are primes, but who's to say p is prime if p = 2qr+1? It's probably *not* prime unless you reject choices of q and r that make p composite. (also, what's x?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Use `BigInteger.modInverse()` -- it will do what you want.</strike>

If you read the docs for `BigInteger.modInverse()` (which performs the identical calculation, but more efficiently than your code; in fact presumably `BigInteger.modPow()` calls `modInverse()` for negative inputs before raising to a power), you'll see:

> Throws: ArithmeticException - m <= 0, or this BigInteger has no multiplicative inverse mod m (that is, this BigInteger is not relatively prime to m).

If you're getting "BigInteger not invertible" this means that x and p are not relatively prime, so there is no mathematically defined inverse for the pair of numbers x and p given as input.

Possibilities:

- p is prime, and x is 0 or a multiple of p
- p is not prime, and x and p have a common factor
- p is not a positive integer (0 or negative), which violates the requirements of `modPow()` and `modInverse()`

Answer (score -2):

Just put `return BigInteger.ZERO`. Any time you invert a number greater than one, your result is between 0 and 1. When this number is represented as an integer, it ends up being 0...

Comment: What is p? The [documentation of modPow][1] says "Throws ArithmeticException if m <= 0".

Comment: @Jason What he's trying to do isn't possible with `modPow`, and is specifically excepted as such. I wasn't aware of `modInverse()`, which is better than `return 0` as I suggested, but the reasoning for why I suggested it is accurate, and useful.

Comment: @glowcoder: your answer was accurate and useful for non-modular arithmetic, but not appropriate for modular arithmetic. (though admittedly the OP might have made it more clear that modular arithmetic was being used)

Comment: @Jason By "more clear" I assume you mean "the slightest bit clear"?  The question, as stated, has *one* reference to modular arithmetic, and it was only in a code sample which very, *very* often is little more than OP trying random methods hoping to get the right result. It is generally accepted in mathematics that "inverse" means `1/x` in normal, run-of-them-mill arithmetic.